# Mongoose aggregate to group by parent id in the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a simple document in mongoDB call company with following schema:

```js
const companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  id: { type: String },
  name: { type: String },
  parentId: { type: String, default: null },
  type: { type: Number },
  active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  number: { type: String },
});
```

Then I have a query to get all companies and group them by parentId and add all sub-companies to branches property.

I got this working to some extend but need a final push to get all I required.

this is my code so far:

```js
Company.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        active: true,
      },
    },

    {
      $project: {
        _id: { $cond: ['$parentId', '$parentId', '$id'] },
        name: 1,
        id: '$id',
        parent: '$parent',
        parentId: { $ifNull: ['$parentId', false] },
      },
    },

    { $sort: { _id: 1, parentId: -1 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        name: { $min: { $cond: ['$parentId', '$name', false] } },
        branches: {
          $push: '$$ROOT',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        name: 1,
        branches: '$branches',
      },
    },
  ])
```

and this is the output I get so far:

```js
{
  "_id": "29689760",
  "name": "Branch 2",
  "branches": [
    { "name": "Test (Head Office)", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29689760", "parentId": false },
    { "name": "Branch 1", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694015", "parentId": "29689760" },
    { "name": "Branch 2", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694016", "parentId": "29689760" },
    { "name": "Branch 3", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694017", "parentId": "29689760" },
    { "name": "Branch 4", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694018", "parentId": "29689760" }
  ]
}
```

What i would need is the main object to return all about the parent company and branches to exclude the parent company, i.e.

```js
{
  "_id": "29689760",
  "name": "Test (Head Office)"",
  "branches": [
//the next line will be missins
    //{ "name": "Test (Head Office)", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29689760", "parentId": false },
    { "name": "Branch 1", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694015", "parentId": "29689760" },
    { "name": "Branch 2", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694016", "parentId": "29689760" },
    { "name": "Branch 3", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694017", "parentId": "29689760" },
    { "name": "Branch 4", "_id": "29689760", "id": "29694018", "parentId": "29689760" }
  ]
}
```

I have tried adding `$lookup` as the first argument in aggregate but this will add info to every branch rather than just in the parent company.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is confusing when conditions in `_id` and `parentId` in `$project` and `$group` stages,

but as per your statement,

> *What i would need is the main object to return all about the parent company and branches to exclude the parent company*

I would suggest a solution in your query, you can change this in `$group` stage,

- put condition when push branch, if `parentId` is false then push root document otherwise `$$REMOVE` to exclude the push

```
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        name: { $min: { $cond: ['$parentId', '$name', false] } },
        branches: {
          $push: {
            $cond: ['$parentId', '$$ROOT', '$$REMOVE']
          }
        },
      },
    },
```

---

The second option you can use `$lookup` to join and get branches from the same collection,

- `$match` your required fields and `parentId` should be null
- `$sort` by `_id` in ascending order
- `$lookup` with current collection
- `$project` to show required fields

```
await Company.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      active: true,
      parentId: null
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'company', // change your original collection name
      localField: 'id', 
      foreignField: 'parentId',
      as: 'branches'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      branches: {
        id: 1,
        name: 1,
        _id: 1,
        parentId: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7qy5Pk5G1mn)

Comment: the condition to remove the parent one works perfectly. But iam having probolem with the name property in the $group. Is there a way to have this as a name of the parent company rather than name of one of the sub companies? Thank you

Comment: can you post example documents in this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) and share the link.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have looked into your answer and realized i havent read it correctly. its all working now perfectly. Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: Hello! I have a similar problem, but in my case I have to group all the parents of the children and then you assign each child to the parents of the same collection. I posted a question trying to find help, do you think you could recommend me what to do?